# Connect PC to Laptop Monitor possible?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi

I want to buy a PC and build it by myself.

I can't buy a monitor now but maybe after 30-40 days from building the PC.

I have a Laptop but it has only **VGA** and **DP** Ports.
There is **DVI** and **HDMI** Ports in the PC mainboard (no external graphics card).

Is it possible to use my Laptop's monitor as my main PC monitor?
Or is there no way but to buy an external Monitor?

I searched but I cant find any thing giving me the answer clearly.

Thanks

Comment: should be possible

Comment: People throw out perfectly good monitors all the time, i find them on the curb all the time here in the usa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The graphic ports in the laptop are usually for graphic *output* only.

A workaround might be (depending on your location) to borrow a monitor from a friend. Once you got the operating system install you can access your PC remotely with your laptop until you can buy a external monitor.

Or get an old monitor. At least in Germany you can get old DVI monitors almost for free. But make sure the graphic card of your PC supports it's connection (even the mainboard does not have an VGA plug in most cases you can use an adapter - check it in the mainboard's manual).

Another suggestion would be to connect it to a TV. "New" TVs usually have some graphic connections like HDMI etc.

There are several more solutions they depend on your particular situation, without more information it's difficult to give you better suggestions. Maybe you could elaborate on the three suggestions first, so we get a little more input.

Comment: I have just bought the PC Build and I bought a new monitor too  : )  Thanks!

Comment: yeah of course!

Answer (score 0):

If your PC and laptop are connected to LAN network and use Windows, you can apply the Spacedesk app.
Client - on Laptop (display)/Server - on PC (source)
https://www.spacedesk.net/