# How to connect VGA Desktop with HDMI Laptop?

Tags: remote-desktop, hdmi, vga, external-display, dvi

I have a computer that is working fine except for my monitor, so I can't do much with my computer. So, now I want to turn my desktop into a private server but I don't have access to my monitor I thought I could use my laptop as a monitor but my laptop only supports HDMI and my desktop only supports VGA.

So, is it possible to use a VGA to HDMI converter in this situation?

Or is there a way to turn my desktop into a server without access to a monitor?

Comment: You don’t. Your laptop does not have a display _input_. It has an HDMI _output_.

Comment: @DanielB So, what else can I do? I also have a smart TV. Can I use it? Again it (TV) only supports HDMI?
I just want to turn my desktop into a server.

Comment: You could get a VGA capture card and essentially "record" the output of your desktop.https://www.google.com/search?q=vga%20capture%20card or you could install something like Teamviewer and remote desktop into it over the network...

Comment: Or VNC, RDP, etc.

Comment: Yes, you can use your TV. There are adapters.

Comment: why not just get a cheap monitor?  it may depend on where you are in the world, but the local thrift shops to me, sell widescreen monitors for under $10.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connect PC to Laptop Monitor possible?](https://superuser.com/questions/1338344/connect-pc-to-laptop-monitor-possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, no - you cannot use your laptop as an output device for another system *directly*: you would need to use ssh, vnc, rdp, etc to get to the remote system

Second, yes - you can most certainly connect your computer to a TV with an adapter (they're a few bucks on Amazon, among hundreds of other sources): just beware getting output resolution correct can *sometimes* be annoying